# Passing $& in replace()-function to another function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, replace

This code will take str and put each word in a `<span>`. I want to add some functionality, so some words will be highlighted, but can't figure out how to pass $& (which is a word) to the highLight function. Right now I have written `{$&}` which does not work.

```
str = "Adam Sandler"
const highLight = (param) => {
 conosle.log(param)
}

const wrapWordsInSpan = (str) => {
   const addedSpanToText = str.replace(
     /\w+/g,
     `<span id="text-container" style="color: ${highLight(`{$&}`)}"}>$&</span>`
   );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're really close, but you have to pass a *function* as the second argument to `replace` if you want to use that value dynamically (for instance, to call `highlight`), like this:

```
const wrapWordsInSpan = (str) => {
    const addedSpanToText = str.replace(
       /\w+/g,
       match => `<span id="text-container" style="color: ${highLight(match)}"}>${match}</span>`
    );
    return addedSpanToText;
};
```

The `` match => `<span id="text-container" style="color: ${highLight(match)}"}>${match}</span>` ``  part is the function. It gets called with the matched text as an argument (the equivalent of the `$&` token in the string), which I've called `match` above (capture group values are subsequent arguments, details [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)). What it returns gets used as the replacement:

```js
const wrapWordsInSpan = (str) => {
    const addedSpanToText = str.replace(
       /\w+/g,
       match => `<span id="text-container" style="color: ${highLight(match)}"}>${match}</span>`
    );
    return addedSpanToText;
};

const highLight = (param) => {
    return param === "Adam" ? "green" : "black";
};

const str = "Adam Sandler"

console.log(wrapWordsInSpan(str));
```

Comment: Great answer! Is there any way to pass the starting index of the word to the function as well?

Never mind, I solved it! As the documentation you linked suggested it was possible to use (p1,p2) instead of match to get the index as p2.